# Does alternating test show divergence?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

My book states the alternating tests' convergence requirements.

However, my book doesnt point out, if $a_n$ fails **one** of the convergence requirements, is it true that is diverges? Such as the limit as $n \to \infty$

If

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \ne 0$$

then does $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}a_n$ diverge Or does the test all together fail?

Comment: If $a_n$ has a non-zero limit then the alternating series sum will certainly not converge to a finite number

Answer (score 2):

A necessary condition for a series to converge is that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$$

This has nothing to do with the alternating series test.
If one of the other hypothesis fails, then one cannot conclude divergence.

Comment: So the test itself fails, and we have to try something else/

Comment: @Amad27 you are correct :)

Comment: The alternating test says $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$ is a requirement for convergence, above you have said it has nothing to do with the test?

Comment: @Amad27 $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ is a requirement for every series, not just alternating series. I mean it really is very general; of course it is a requirement for alternating series, because is a requirement for every series

Answer (score 1):

The following alternating series fails the alternating series test with flying colors
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\dfrac{\cos^2\left(n\right)}{n^2}.$$

This series is however is absolutely convergent, which is easy to show.

In addition, you can take many absolutely convergent series which **do** pass the test and create one which does not:

Given $\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n b_n\ $ where $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges, and $b_n < b_{n-1}$ for all $n$. Make a new series by defining $a_{2n-1} = b_{2n}$ and $a_{2n}=b_{2n-1}$. Then $\{a_n\}$ is not decreasing, as for all $n$, $a_{2n-1}=b_{2n}<b_{2n-1}=a_{2n}$. However, because the original series is absolutely convergent

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n b_n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$$